# How to avoid light flares in long exposure night shots

Tags: long-exposure, night, light, lens-flare

I keep viewing other photographers night shots and see that they're very clear shots, when I shoot even with the same settings, my shots aren't so clear..
here's example:
[image]

Question is: How to avoid light flares in long expo night shots?

Comment: remove filters like UV filters and use a lens hood.

Comment: @CountIblis Your comment sounds like the seed of a decent answer. [Short answers as comments — please resist the urge](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/11924)

Comment: @Arkadi How clean is the front of your lens? How sure are you about that? How many filters do you have screwed onto the front of your lens? Is your lens a relatively new design with multi-coating on both side of most lens elements or an older film-era design that doesn't have anti-reflective coatings on the back side of lens elements?

Comment: @scottbb I'm pretty sure it's an answer that has already been written here multiple times to multiple questions.

Comment: @MichaelClark probably so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Michael Clark's & Count Iblis' very valid suggestions, another solution is to not aim your camera towards exceptionally bright lights, although that may defeat the type of shot you want.

The specific angle at which the light enters the lens, together with the design of the lens, will determine how significant the lens flare is and where it shows in the picture.